# If then else in XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the next expression:

```
population = tree.xpath('(//tr/td/b/a[contains(text(), "Population")]/../../following-sibling::td/span/following-sibling::text())[1] or'
                            '//tr/td/b/a[contains(text(), "Population")]/../../following-sibling::td/span/text())
```

which returns 'True'.

If I use "|" instead of 'or', it combines values of the 1st and 2nd paths, like this `['11 061 886', '▼']`.

How to make the logic like:

```
If the 1st path exists:
    get the 1st value
elif the 2nd path exists:
    get the 2nd value
else:
    pass
```

?

I understand that this is simple, but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really can't find an XPath 2.0 processor, there are some workarounds in XPath 1.0 which may work for you.

If you want to select node-sets, then in place of

```
if (A) then B else C
```

you can write

```
B[A] | C[not(A)]
```

while remembering that the condition A may have to be changed because the context node is different.

If you want to return strings, then in place of

```
if (A) then B else C
```

you can use the hideous workaround

```
concat(substring(B, 1, boolean(A) div 0), substring(C, 1, not(A) div 0))
```

which relies on the fact that (true div 0) is positive infinity, while (false div 0) is NaN.

(I think I've got that right. It's years since I have used XPath 1.0. But there is some such expression that works.)

For numbers, you can use

```
B * boolean(A) + C * not(A)
```

replying on false=0, true=1.

For a multiple conditional like

```
if (A) then X else if (B) then Y else Z
```

you can use similar logic, for example with node-sets it becomes

```
X[A] | Y[not(A) and B] | Z[not(A or B)]
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for the answer. I have a little question. If I change my expression according to your workaround, the expression becomes too long (in your example 'A' repeated 3 times and 'B' twice) and I have some expressions with up to 5 nodes\paths. Would it be shorter in case if I find XPath 2.0 processor? If so, could you provide v2.0 implementation? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, this kind of thing is much easier in XPath 2.0. There are quite a few XPath 2.0 implementations around (especially if you include XQuery 1.0, which is a superset of XPath 2.0), but there are some environments (e.g. PHP or Python) that aren't well served, so it all depends on your platform.

Comment: my platform is Python

Comment: You have my sympathy.