# How to remove third name of a cell with 4 names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of people names with 4 words [firstName secondName thirdName FamilyName].
I need to remove third Name of the cell .
Please help ..

Example:  *reem fahad ali almuhana*
Expected output:  *reem fahad almuhana*

I have tried
`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(F2))), (3-1)*LEN(F2)+1, LEN(F2)))`

Comment: Do you have a sample of an actuall cell value including some expected output? Please also, don't forget to include what you have tried yourself.

Comment: sample : reem fahad ali almuhana 
expected output :  reem fahad almuhana 
I tried below equation to get the third name but how to remove it ? 
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(F2))), (3-1)*LEN(F2)+1, LEN(F2)))

Comment: Do all entries have a third name, or a second name for that matter?

Answer (score 3):

You can try below approach:

`=LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),1)+1))&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

You can let go of some of the `TRIM` parts like below if your data is consistent in terms of separating spaces.

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1))&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

Comment: Would this also work for entries that don't have a third name, or entries that only have a first and last name?

Comment: @Luuklag for 3 values in a cell,it won't remove anything so I am tempted to say that is a yes but it is OP's call I suppose. For cells with only 2 entries it will produce error.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to handle this issue would be @shrivallabha.redij's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61498236/9758194) but for fun and the sake of alternative means; try a combination of `FILTERXML`, `TEXTJOIN` and some `XPATH` magic =)

---

**Option 1):** Your original question; remove the thrid name in a cell with 4 names:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()!=3]"))
```

[image]

---

**Option 2):** Same rules as above, but check if 4 names exists first:

While the first option would also remove "ali" from "reem fahad ali", we can apply some cool `OR` logic. Because Excel uses `XPATH 1.0` we have to apply the `|` to mimic the expression. More details about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191585/if-then-else-in-xpath-1-0):

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[count(//s)<4]|//s[position()!=3]"))
```

Now we check if there are actually 4 names within the cell. If any less, then nothing happends, otherwise the thrid name in the cell will be deleted.

[image]

---

**Option 3:** Same rules as above, but remove a range of names:

Where option two would delete the thrid name from a cell, you might be interested to delete the 3rd up to the second to last cell. Meaning, we can apply this to names larger than 4 and get away with the first two and last concatenated:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[count(//s)<4]|//s[position()<3 or position()=last()]"))
```

[image]

---

**Note1:** Enter all above options through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note2:** By no means am I an `XPATH` guru. So possibly other (better) expressions out there.

Good luck!

Comment: +1, I liked the idea. I also came up with `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),{1,2,3,4}*99,99)),{1,2,4}))` but didn't post as I am not sure OP's excel version.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, yeah it's just for sake of experimenting here as I want to try more xpath solutions (it's fun).

Answer (score 0):

1. use notepad++ create a new txt file
2. copy all of that to file
3. replace the space between words to '\t'
4. then copy all of the words back to excel then words comes into diffrent cells
5. delete the third column
6. you have no thirdNames now
7. do that again copy all of that back to txt file
8. replace '\t' to space
9. copy all of that back to excel
10. all the words of a name come into one cell